# Tell iTerm2 not to remember open windows on quit

Tags: iterm

After a recent upgrade of iTerm2 (I'm on build 1.0.0.20120203), when I open up iTerm2, it restores all of the terminal windows I had open. How do I disable this behavior so it doesn't "remember" how many windows I had open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the resume feature introduced with Lion.

```
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

Comment: Or (assuming it's Lion, and not an iTerm feature), remember to hold down the Alt/Option key whenever you Quit, which will work in any application.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. It doesn't work with any application though. E.g. Chrome's setting in it's preferences overrides the shortcut.