# Disable opening tabs in iTerm2 on when the application starts?

Tags: iterm

iTerm2, on startup, opens as many tabs as were opened in my previous session. How can I disable this behaviour? I don't need those empty tabs.

Comment: Have You tried this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41904/tell-iterm2-not-to-remember-open-windows-on-quit?rq=1

Comment: yes. not working

Answer (score 2):

Close all windows and tabs, except only one, or arrange windows and tabs the way you want, and then:

1. **Windows > Save Window Arrangement**
2. **Preferences > Arrangements > Set default**
3. **Preferences > General > Startup** and Select **Open Default Window Arrangement**

PS: iTerm restores all sessions when you disable the **Close windows when quit app** in System preferences

Comment: i tried it. one terminal with restored tabs and one with default arrangement were opened. "Close windows when quit app" is enabled

Comment: check the file in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.googlecode.iterm2.savedState`